# Different behavior on a mobile device?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, mobile, facebook

I'm developing Facebook connect for a forum (vBulletin) and we have a mobile skin which allows mobile device users to use a friendlier style.

This Facebook connect was drafted together without the mobile skin in mind, but now plans have moved to incorporate the mobile skin. What I want to know is will mobile devices act differently when authenticating oauth and if so, how will it act differently?

Looking forward to your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Same API methods etc

See here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/